# How to define external classes of a node module in separate files - kotlinjs

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

I'm attempting to write a wrapper for an npm package but I cannot figure out how to define classes within a module in a separate file. It works fine if I do it within the single class but the file will end up being huge and messy if I go that route...

Imagine for example, there is this `index.js` file in the npm package:

```
module.exports = {
    AnotherClass: require('./somePath/AnotherClass')
}
```

Which I can do as:

```
@JsModule("testmodule")
@JsNonModule
external class TestModule {
    class AnotherClass {
        val someProperty: Type
    }
}
```

But I want to define `AnotherClass` in a separate (kotlin) file, just for better organisation and ease of navigation.

I've attempted (for sake of the example): `@JsModule("testmodule/AnotherClass")` as well as `@JsModule("testmodule/somepath/AnotherClass")` neither of which appear to work.